# Using a method that is another Page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there any way to get access to methods that are on other pages? I.E Using methods that are in the SecondPage class in the Mainpage class? Or is there way of making methods global ( i.e methods that span all pages ) ?

Comment: How about making a global public class?

Comment: I make my methods private instance methods, when I should have made the public static methods,thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a way to solve the problem, make the methods you want to use PUBLIC STATIC methods, then if you want to use those methods on another page, just add go

```
  NamespaceName.PageName.MethodName( var Args );
```

Comment: This is a quite bad approach. Think of creating a kind of service class for such things. And of course is better to keep logic in ViewModels instead of pages (except for quite view-specific one).

Comment: If it makes sense for the method to be public and static then it probably doesn't belong on a page.  It should be in a 3rd class specifically for such utility methods.

Answer (score 0):

> You should use public static methods

This is a bad approach , you can make a service class